# Почему добавляется ненужный padding?

Tags: html, css

При добавлении `padding-right` к первому тегу `p`, появляется лишний `padding-right` у второго тега `p`. В чем проблема?

HTML

```
<div id="hdr_login">
    <p>ALREADY USER? <span style="color:#b85474;">LOGIN</span></p>
    <p>SIGN UP</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hdr_login {
    float: right;
}
#hdr_login p {
    outline:1px solid black;
    color:#3a5878;
    margin:0;
}
#hdr_login p:first-child {
    padding-right: 18px;
}
#hdr_login p:last-child {
    background: #ca748f;
    padding:14px 54px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jyLmX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не `padding` добавляется а ширина, `<p>` прилипает к левой стороне `<div>` и расширяется до конца. Поставьте `padding-left` вместо `padding-right` и всё увидите, чтобы этого не было надо например ширину явно указать. Или так:

HTML

```
<div id="hdr_login">
    <p>ALREADY USER? <span style="color:#b85474;">LOGIN</span></p>
    <p>SIGN UP</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hdr_login {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#hdr_login p {
    outline:1px solid black;
    color:#3a5878;
    margin:0;
}
#hdr_login p:first-child {
    padding-left: 18px;
}
#hdr_login p:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #ca748f;
    padding:14px 54px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jyLmX/1/

Comment: Спасибо, все понял!